# Openslide: Replace "label" image

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, openslide

I'm using openslide-python to read whole slide images in the Mirax format (mrxs). Now I'd like to replace the "label" barcode image with a custom one. Unfortunately,

```
f.associated_images["label"] = label_new
```

raises

```
TypeError: '_AssociatedImageMap' object does not support item assignment
```

I found that the "label" reference is stored in the image-associated slidedat.ini file

```
NONHIER_0_VAL_3 = ScanDataLayer_SlideBarcode
```

But I am not sure what to do with this information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Mario

Answer (score 0):

`openslide` is reading library, not writing.

You need to create writing library for MIRAX support yourself.

In `Dataxxx.dat` you keep MIRAX header and image data (in jpg or png format). In    `Index.dat` you keep information about dat file (file index and file size)
In `Slidedat.ini` you put information about your barcode image:

```
NONHIER_0_VAL_3 = ScanDataLayer_SlideBarcode
NONHIER_0_VAL_3_SECTION = NONHIERLAYER_0_LEVEL_3_SECTION
NONHIER_0_VAL_3_IMAGENUMBER_X = 1
NONHIER_0_VAL_3_IMAGENUMBER_Y = 1
```

and

```
[NONHIERLAYER_0_LEVEL_3_SECTION]
BARCODE_IMAGE_TYPE = JPEG
BARCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1782
BARCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1252
```